# npm package minimatch: npm force resolutions not updating dependency

Tags: npm, package, npm-install, package.json, npm-scripts

In my package.json, I have multiple dependencies using "minimatch". I am using npm-force-resolutions to force a package version when I need to. In this case, in my resolutions, I have

```
  "resolutions": {
    "minimatch": "~3.0.5"
  }
```

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, all minimatch dependencies are updated except one, under graphql-config (with version 3.4.1). I don't understand why this minimatch version does not update like the others. It's under @graphql-codegen/cli => @graphql-config => minimatch.

So, my question is what do I need to change or add in my package.json so this package version gets updated ?

Answer (score 1):

what is the npm version you are using? if it's above 8.3, you can use overrides https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides